# How to obtain pointer to GstPipeline from GstElement returned from gst_parse_launch?

Tags: gstreamer

I am porting a python GStreamer 1.0 example (play-master.py - noraisin.net), from python to C, and do not understand how to get a pointer to the pipeline. In the python bindings, it seems to be abstracted so the element and pipeline are used interchangeably.

```
...

GstElement* element = gst_parse_launch("playbin", &error);

gst_element_set_start_time(element, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE);

GstClock* clock = gst_element_get_clock(element);
gst_pipeline_use_clock( ???, clock);

...
```

So, `gst_pipeline_use_clock` needs a pointer to a `GstPipeline` struct, but `gst_parse_launch` returns a pointer to a `GstElement` which, if I understand correctly, has a pointer to the pipeline. How do I access it?

Here is same code in python:

```
Gst.init()

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('playbin')

pipeline.set_start_time(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE)

clock = pipeline.get_clock()
pipeline.use_clock(clock)
```

Answer (score 3):

You wrap the `GstElement*` with the `GST_PIPELINE` macro, for example:

```
GstPipeline *pipeline = GST_PIPELINE(gst_parse_launch("playbin", &error));
```

Similar macros exist to convert to other element types.